# React js different values after JSON.stringify(obj)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I did:

I created a class in React to handle the form control of a react HTML Form.

Create an object like:

```
  class FormController extends Component {
   
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);

       var tempFormInputs = {};

       //read all (html)input names and values from children and create an 
       // object for each pair into the tempform

       var currentElement;
       for (var x = 0; x < this.props.children.props.children.length; x++) 
       {
            currentElement= this.props.children.props.children[x]
            tempFormInputs[currentElement.props.name] = { 
                  value: '',
                  error: false,
                  required: currentElement.props.required
            }
       }
    
       this.state = {
            formularData: tempFormInputs,
       }
    }
       //function called from child on change
       onComponentChange(value, Evname) {
        this.state.formularData[Evname].value = value;
       }
   
   //function connected to a Button
   //triggered on click

   onClickSave() {
       console.log(this.state.formularData);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.formularData));
       this.props.submitCallback(this.formularData);
   }
 }
```

So if I change the name field from 'aaa' to 'aab', the following problem occurred

On in `onClickSave` the first `console.log` prints this:
(I removed the error, required in an unimportet step)

```
{
    name: {value: "aaa"}
    serviceID: {value: "1"}
    ...
}
```

The second one this:

```
{"name":{"value":"aab"},"serviceID":{"value":"1"}}
```

Can someone tell me why the values are different?

---

**EDIT:**

okay i think i figured out where the error is:

in the onClickSave() function i callback to another function, like:

```
 onClickSave() {
        console.log(this.state.formularData);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.formularData));
        this.props.submitCallback(this.formularData);
}
```

without the callback the values are the same, with the callback the values differ

Comment: Why are you mutating the state directly and not using `setState`?

Comment: Console output is live, my guess is that the output of `console.log(this.state.formularData);` changes right after those two lines run; the stringify line shows the data at the time of the logging, the other one shows the current content

Comment: Also, why is `onComponentChange` method inside the constructor? That looks like a syntax error.

Comment: @adiga i dont want to update the component at this time

Comment: @adiga the onComponentChange method is now outside, sorry, was a typo

Answer (score -2):

This the normal behavior of JSON.stringify(obj) function. If you put any json in it, the function changes it's key and values to string format.

Comment: My problem is not the string format, it is, that the values are different and i can´t figure out why